# Accessing google api's with Sencha 2

Tags: extjs, google-api, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to access google places api with Sencha 2. I am using Ajax but I am getting cross origin request error (Testing in Chrome browser).

I cannot use jsonp as google api does not support response with callback parameter.

Does Sencha 2 provide any API to achieve this or do I have to route the response of api through my server?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details about which Google API you are trying to access, the exact error message you are receiving, and the snippet of code you are using to make the request? There are many Google APIs that support JSON-P.

Comment: I am trying google "places" API. However, I can use it through JS library that they provide. It works perfectly now, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found Google provides JS library to access the same places API.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

It works perfectly now without the need to have ajax calls.

Thanks